# Getting an API error when adding CIDRs into Managed Prefix List on AWS using AWS Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-go

I am facing a very strange situation here. I currently have a completely new [Managed Prefix List](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html) provisioned in my AWS account. No CIDRs registered in it.

My objective is to have those CIDRs loaded by an external service written in Go using the AWS Go SDK. The part of my code that actually loads the CIDR list is the one I'm sending below

```
func (a AWSPrefixListRepository) AddCidrs(cidrs []domain.Cidr, resource string, currentVersion int64) error {

    svc := ec2.New(a.sess)

    _, err := svc.ModifyManagedPrefixList(&ec2.ModifyManagedPrefixListInput{
        CurrentVersion: &currentVersion,
        PrefixListId:   &resource,
        AddEntries:     a.buildAddEntries(cidrs),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (a AWSPrefixListRepository) buildAddEntries(cidrs []domain.Cidr) []*ec2.AddPrefixListEntry {
    var addEntries []*ec2.AddPrefixListEntry

    for _, cidr := range cidrs {
        addEntries = append(addEntries, &ec2.AddPrefixListEntry{
            Cidr:        &cidr.PrefixIpv4,
            Description: &cidr.Description,
        })
    }

    return addEntries
}
```

The problem happens when `cidrs []domain.Cidr` has more than one item. Then I get the error below

> CIDR (99.79.87.237/32) is a duplicate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That was totally my mistake.

Interact over `cidrs` slice using a `range` creates a single `cidr` variable with a fixed address, no matter how many cidrs the slice has

Basically, all assignments to `Cidr` and `Description` ended up by being the last `cidr` item of the slice. So yeah, it's indeed a duplicating

Therefore, the API message makes sense now and I managed to get this by enabling the debugging level of the SDK.